# does calling notify makes any sense in the following context

Tags: concurrency, wait

I have following code block which gets a lock and perform operations.   I don't have any `wait()` called inside the `synchronized` block.

```
Object obj = new Object();
...
someMethod() {
    synchronized (obj) {
        try {
            Some operations  but no wait() is there.
        } finally {
            obj.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

As i need some operation which needs locking.

Does calling notify makes any sense?  Could there be a case that could hold a lock and not allow other threads to execute?  There is no way for the code to get into an infinite loop, but yes an exception might be thrown.

Comment: if this the only method which makes synchronized access to obj, then call to notify can be dropped.

Comment: I tried to fix the english.  Feel free to edit if I screwed it up.  You should consider adding a language tag to the question.  Maybe java?

Comment: You question still doesn't really make sense.  Can you flesh it out a bit?

Comment: @Gray , thanks for your effort , apologies for not  making my question clear , What i am trying to understand, can there be any issues in my code which could block other threads - any case, for example say inside synchronized block I am trying to calculate factorial , number is an instance variable in the class , so inside the block i set the number and call the method that cal factorial, just an example .

Comment: Please edit your post with this information.